# Which User Group or Rule or Condition to use for a user to access CMP's Content pages

Tags: content-hub

Using `Content Hub v4.2`
I have created custom *User Groups* (UGs) following the default ones (with the exact Rules, Conditions & Permissions):

```
     M.Builtin.Readers => MyApp.Readers
     M.Builtin.Creators => MyApp.Creators
     M.Builtin.Editors => MyApp.Editors
     M.Builtin.Approvers => MyApp.Approvers
     M.Builtin.CMP.Everyone => MyApp.CMP.Everyone
```

For all these custom UGs, the available `Modules` (*Media & Content*), are selected.

Then, created respective users like this:

| Username | Policy Combination Sets |
| --- | --- |
| myapp_reader | **Any:** Everyone; **All:** MyApp.Readers, MyApp.CMP.Everyone |
| myapp_creator | **Any:** Everyone; **All:** MyApp.Creators, MyApp.Editors, MyApp.CMP.Everyone |
| myapp_approver | **Any:** Everyone; **All:** MyApp.Approvers, MyApp.CMP.Everyone |

Cleared the cache for UGs & Users.

When I log in as each of these users, for all of them I only see **"Collections" & "Assets**" in the top menu.

I'm expecting, the CMP's `Content` dropdown should be visible to all of them. The `Create` page should be available to `myapp_creator/myapp_approver`.

Please also provide any official documentation available that explains the logic.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

For all the users, I have removed the `All` combinations and moved all `User Groups` under `Any`. Now I'm able to access the CMP module.
But not sure, if this is the right way.

Comment: Did you check this? https://anbrue.net/2021/11/15/sitecore-content-hub-setup-custom-usergroups-for-cmp/

Comment: @SumitBhatia Tried the document. In the "First" step, it says "ContentVisualization" which isn't available for me. I stopped here as from the 2nd step it talks abt stateflow. I'm unable to see the module itself.